# How to escape apostrophe (') in SharePoint KQL query

Tags: search, sharepoint-2013, taxonomy

I have a term  `Droits de l'homme` in term set `Themes`.

Field using this term set are mapped to `Themes` Managed Property in SharePoint 2013 search.
I try to make a SharePoint Search KQL query that will return all items with this term:
`Themes="Droits de l'homme"`

This does not return all expected results. It looks that the apostrophe character (') breaks the query in some way.

Query `Themes:"Droits de l*"` returns good results.

How do I properly escape the apostrophe in [property restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/keyword-query-language-kql-syntax-reference#property-restriction-queries-in-kql) queries in KQL?

Comment: Ever find any solution to this?

Comment: Unfortunately no.